# useProxy on URLLoader? similar to that of the httpservice?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, httpservice, urlloader, urlrequest

Loading Https images over untrusted servers have limitations. We have decided to load images over from the proxyservice rather than let the air do it itself form several domains. When I checked blazeds document, httpservice has useproxy property to divert the service call to the proxy-service.xml rather than client doing it by itslef. Can I do the same for the URLLoader?

Comment: This question confuses me greatly.  What BlazeDS Document did you check?

Comment: Why not look at the HTTPService source code (F3 in Flash Builder) and see how they do it.

Comment: Blazeds document for proxy-config.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have decided to use tomcat valves for loading the images, valves act as a proxy for loading the images from https domains.